# Can't redirect URLs to index.php with .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, model-view-controller, xampp

I am following along Traversy Media's [PHP OOP and MVC course](https://www.udemy.com/course/object-oriented-php-mvc/).  I'm on lecture 15 with bootstrap file and Core class.

I can't seem to have URLs redirect to the index.php page.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/ohmyMVC/index.php?url=thisisURL
```

returns thisisURL. but this

```
http://localhost:8080/ohmyMVC/thisisURL
```

returns

````
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.0 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0```
````

Here is my Core Class:

```
  class Core {
    protected $currentController = 'Pages';
    protected $currentMethod = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct(){
      $this->getUrl();
    }

    public function getUrl(){
      echo $_GET['url'];   
    }
  }
```

Here is my bootstrap.php

```
<?php

// Load Libraries

require_once 'libraries/Core.php';
require_once 'libraries/Controller.php';
require_once 'libraries/Database.php';
```

.htaccess in public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /traversymvc/public
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Index.php

````
<?php

    require_once '../app/bootstrap.php';

//Init Core Lib

    $init = new Core;```
````

Here is my httpd.conf file

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? What happens when you remove the IfModule wrapper around the directives, do you get any errors? Is Apache set to read .htaccess files to begin with?

Comment: I get this error with the ifModule wrapper removed: 
``` Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
192.168.64.2
Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.0 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0```

I am currently using XAMPP and whats interesting is that I tried it with MAMP and this is the error I got before removing the wrapper in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

The folder in the htaccess file did not match the folder I wanted to access.  The .htaccess file says /TraversyMVC/public whereas I named my folder /ohmyMVC/public.